# How to install to install opencv-python in rpi 3b

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I want to install opencv-python in rpi 3b. I have 32-bit Raspbian OS running on a 1Gb ram raspberry pi. When I type:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

This happens:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a1/d6/8422797e35f8814b1d9842530566a949d9b5850a466321a6c1d5a99055ee/opencv-python-4.3.0.38.tar.gz (88.0MB)
    99% |████████████████████████████████| 88.0MB 1.5MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

And then when I try to import it, it says:

```
No module named cv2
```

Please Help

Comment: if you didn't get `100% `then maybe it didn't install it. Maybe you have two Python installed and `pip` install it for one Python but you run code with other Python - it is common mistake. You should check version `pip -V` and `python -V` or you could use `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: or maybe it need something more. Python module is wraper on C++ library and it may need to install ie. `libopencv-core4.2` using `apt install ...`. You may have also `opencv-python` in `apt` as `python3-opencv` and it can be specially created for RPi. You should check `apt search opencv`

Comment: you could also check on blog `pyImageSearch` - [Install OpenCV 4 on your Raspberry Pi](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/) but it describe how to compile it from source code.

Answer (score 0):

For python3 use pip3 `pip3 install opencv-python`
be careful if you don't use a virtual environment, an installation on user "pi" will be valid only for "pi", if your script needs to be executed as root `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`